# How to remove dupefilter on specific domain using CrawlSpider and Rules?

Tags: scrapy

I have CrawlSpider that takes multiple URLs as `start_urls` and then I have several Rules for them. One of the Rules is used to handle pagination:

```
class MySpider(CrawlSpider):
    name = 'spdr'

    start_urls = [
        i.strip() for i in open('list.txt', 'r').read().splitlines() if i and i.strip()
    ]
    rules = [
        Rule(
            LinkExtractor(
                allow=[], 
                restrict_css=[
                    "a[rel='next']",
                    "a[href*='nav_top-next']",
                ],
                
            ),
            follow=True,
        ),
    ...
```

The problem is that one of the websites redirects spider to the initial URL (`https://piwi.wiesbaden.de/gremium/detail/1/mitgliederaktuell?0`) when it tries to paginate and in that case it is dupefiltered and not crawled:

```
2023-01-13 21:35:51 [scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.redirect] DEBUG: Redirecting (302) to <GET https://piwi.wiesbaden.de/gremium/detail/1/mitgliederaktuell?0> from <GET https://piwi.wiesbaden.de/gremium/detail/1/mitgliederaktuell;jsessionid=F45A1D3CC4EF7F8D27A606FD4521685B?0-1.-list-nav_top-next>
```

So, I need to avoid filtering duplicates in one specific domain. Is it possible to do? Please advise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `process_request` parameter for your `Rule` to set a function that checks each request for the specific url, and if found then you can set the requests `dont_filter` argument to True.

for example:

```py
def check_url(request, response):
    if request.url == MySpider.url_you_dont_want_to_filter:
        request.dont_filter = True
    return request

class MySpider(CrawlSpider):
    name = 'spdr'
    url_you_dont_want_to_filter = 'https://www.example.com/dont_filter_me'  # added this

    start_urls = [
        i.strip() for i in open('list.txt', 'r').read().splitlines() if i and i.strip()
    ]
    rules = [
        Rule(
            LinkExtractor(
                allow=[], 
                restrict_css=[
                    "a[rel='next']",
                    "a[href*='nav_top-next']",
                ],
                
            ),
            follow=True,
            process_request=check_url,   # added this
        ),
    ...
```

Comment: Thanks! That worked for me, but I made my `check_url` function MySpider's class method.